# Does aspectj have access to implicit parameters on a method in Scala?

Tags: scala, aop, aspectj, implicit

I'm using aspectJ to do some user authentication.  It would be really nice to have the userId as an implicit parameter to a method.  But I don't know if an aspectJ joinPoint can see an implicit parameter.

Anyone else try this?

Comment: Have you looked at the class file using `javap`? The implicit parameter should turn up as a "normal" parameter. So from aspectj's point of view, it should be possible to handle it the "normal" way.

Comment: sorry, I don't think I understand what you mean.  Are you suggesting that I try and see how aspectj renders the signature?  I was hoping to not have to do that.  But if that's what I have to do, of course, I'd do it.  I was just hoping someone might have the answer out there.

Comment: aspectj does not really render a signature, it just "looks" at it. That's what I wanted to point out with `javap`. Anyway, I have tested it, and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a service

```
class User(val name: String) {
  override def toString = s"$name"
}

class Service {
  def run()(implicit user: User) {
    println(user.name)
  }
```

the implicit parameter just turns up as a "normal" argument in the class file (output from `javap`):

```
public class app.scala.Service extends java.lang.Object{
    public void run(app.scala.User);
    public app.scala.Service();
}
```

so using a "normal" AspectJ pointcut like:

```
before(Service s, User user) : 
    call(void Service.run(User)) && target(s) && args(user) {

    System.out.println("Hello from AspectJ (before service run)");
    System.out.println("  "  + user);
}
```

works (applied to the .class files generated by `scalac`).

From aspectj's point of view, an implicit parameter is nothing special. The Scala compiler merges arguments from multiple argument lists into a single one, and this is stored in the .class file.

Comment: fair enough.  as long as the weave is done either at loadtime or at compile time on the compiled scala classes, it should be fine.